# Existing tables do not get linked to the Azure Mobile App service

Tags: database, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile App service for the first time. I have an existing database which is hosted by Azure. I used this database when creating the App service. I followed this tutorial [here](http://chrisrisner.com/Connecting-an-Existing-Database-to-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services) which demonstrates how to use existing database. I first created the schema with the same name as the App service and then transferred all tables to that schema. Now I'm trying to access these tables from the Azure portal. I went to Easy Tables tab and created the tables with the same name as in my database and when I click into the table, I don't see any records that are already in the database. The new table that was created, doesn't have the same fields as the tables in my database. They have the following fields : "ID", "CREATEDAT", "UPDATEDAT", "VERSION", "DELETED". The tutorial I followed seemed to have worked for many people. I have the primary keys in my tables with the name "id".
Can anyone give me an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you followed a tutorial meant for Azure Mobile Services and applied it to Azure App Service - these are two totally different things.  Probably most importantly, your tables are not in the [dbo] schema, which is where Easy Tables expects them to be (unless you configure the app service otherwise).  In addition, Mobile Services used double-underscore before the system properties, whereas App Service does not.

If you want to use your existing database, follow the instructions in my App Service Mobile Apps tutorial here:  https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-19-asp-net-table-controllers/

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I've gone through your tutorials and found them to be very helpful. I thought the underlying structure to both services would be same. I went through the tutorial on migrating azure mobile service to azure mobile app and it said that the "Data" tab in the management portal has been changed to Easy tables in the Azure app service. So does this mean I don't need to alter the schema and just add the tables under dbo schema? I'll have a read of the link you provided